# gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark submits jobs as root user

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hadoop-yarn, gcloud

I am trying to submit a spark job using 'gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark', I have set the spark.master as yarn. When the job executes on the dataproc cluster it is executed using the root user, Is there a way I could run it using the google user I have authenticated in gcloud or set a proxy user in the command.

sample command:-

```
 gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
    --cluster gov-demo --region europe-west4 \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.WordCount \
    --jars gs://governance-demo/spark-examples-1.0.jar \
    -- gs://governance-demo/words1.txt
```

Expected :-

> job to be submitted via the google user/some way to provide proxy user

Actual :-

> job gets submitted via the root user

.

Comment: man, have you tried just with `sudo`??

Comment: @KenrySanchez I am trying to execute the command on my local system. I don't think using 'sudo' will help.

Comment: ahhh ok, you're trying from your local computer, in that way. now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into the gcloud dataproc command and you have 2 flags that might do what you need.

For example you have the:

`--account` gcloud global flag. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--account).

> Google Cloud Platform user account to use for invocation. Overrides
>   the default core/account property value for this command invocation.

or the `--impersonate-service-account` flag.

> For this gcloud invocation, all API requests will be made as the given service account instead of the currently selected account. This is done without needing to create, download, and activate a key for the account. In order to perform operations as the service account, your currently selected account must have an IAM role that includes the iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission for the service account. The roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator role has this permission or you may create a custom role. Overrides the default auth/impersonate_service_account property value for this command invocation.

More info about --impersonate-service-account usage, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--impersonate-service-account).

Hope this helps.